# How can I save image from Deepface detectFace?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

I use Deepface to detect and align faces

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import cv2

align_face = DeepFace.detectFace("base/g3.jpg")
```

So I need to save image to jpg from align_fac.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

detectFace function returns in scale of [0, 1]. That's the expected range for matplotlib. I mean that you can plot it with matplotlib as is.

On the other hand, opencv expects images in scale of [0, 255]. That's why, you should denormalize it with multiplying 255. Besides, opencv uses BGR instead of RGB. You should also make this transformation with [:, :, ::-1].

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

detected_face = DeepFace.detectFace( "base/g3.jpg", detector_backend = 'opencv')

plt.imshow(detected_face)
plt.show()

detected_face = detected_face * 255
cv2.imwrite("face.jpg", detected_face[:, :, ::-1])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting. And for the guy who asked so is it, i guess. ) I'd prefer to deal with dlib, cv2 etc.directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import cv2

align_face = DeepFace.detectFace("base/g3.jpg")
cv2.imwrite("face.jpg", align_face)
```

Comment: So, this code does writes face image to file. You may want to RGB2BGR it and denormalize to 255 as well.